# Several Adapters how to know what which one is causing E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I happen to have 6 adapters and on my fragment whenever I try to add data into my SQLite I get this error, however the data is created it does not display on my fragment but I get this, Android does not tell me which adapter has issues, how can I spot the error? and change this?    E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using up to 6 RecyclerViews in different pages to display list of data from your SQLite database.
In the case like this, what I suggest is that you could print out the id of each RecyclerView in onCreate() or onCreateView()(of Fragment) through Logcat. So that, the next time you see the error, search for the latest id printed out, it should be the RecyclerView without the adapter attached.